# C# Windows Forms object

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently in a Windows Forms project with several forms. Each form has 2 objects (pictureBoxes) with the same name. One called 'pBoxMale' and the other 'pBoxFemale'.

Can I use this method in both forms without the need to copy and paste?

```
public void changeVisiblity(int column) // Change profile gender icon's visibility
{
    string tempGender = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(column).ToString();
    if (tempGender == "M")
    {
        pBoxMale.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        pBoxFemale.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: So both forms have the same `dRow` as well?

Comment: yes. each accessing the same table in an access db

Comment: You will need to keep a pointer to each form, and use it to access pBoxMale/Female

Comment: Hmm, you never set it to false.  Better: pBoxMale.Visible = tempGender == "M";

Answer (score 4):

Create a Parent Form:

```
public class ParentForm: Form
    {
        PictureBox pBoxMale { get; set; }

        PictureBox pBoxFemale { get; set; }

        public void changeVisiblity(int column, DataRow dRow) // Change profile gender icon's visibility
        {
            string tempGender = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(column).ToString();
            if (tempGender == "M")
            {
                pBoxMale.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                pBoxFemale.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

And then have each of your Form inherit from Parent form:

```
 public partial class Form1 : ParentForm
    {
       ...
```

Comment: @Johnny, don't blindly copy and paste and post "it don't work" or in your case "I'm getting this: picture".  Engage your brain and work it thru.  Instead of viewing this as an answer to memorize,  break it down into parts and study how to assemble those parts to create an answer.